# Jest encountered an unexpected token - export dnd-core angular-skyhook

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I am using Angular 11 and I am facing an issue in running a spec file.

**I get below error:**

```
    FAIL   rms-management  apps/rms-management/src/app/full-map-view/full-map-view/full-map-view.component.spec.ts

  ● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.      

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Workspace\RM\RMS-portal\node_modules\dnd-core\dist\esm\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './interfaces';                                                                                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at ../../node_modules/@angular-skyhook/core/bundles/angular-skyhook-core.umd.js:2:155
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@angular-skyhook/core/bundles/angular-skyhook-core.umd.js:5:2)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.354 s
Ran all test suites matching /full-map-view.component.spec.ts/i.
```

My **jest.preset.js**:

```
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset');
module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  resolver: '@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
  passWithNoTests: true
};
```

My **jest.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/rms-management',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer.js',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer.js'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!dnd-core/).+\\.js$',
    '/node_modules/(?!lodash-es)'
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer'
      ]
    }
  },
  displayName: 'rms-management'
};
```

My **tsconfig.base.json**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@rms-management/core": [
        "libs/core/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/notification": [
        "libs/notification/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/interfaces": [
        "libs/interfaces/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@drms-management/ui": [
        "libs/ui/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/util-testing": [
        "libs/util-testing/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/e2e": [
        "libs/e2e/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/gcp-client": [
        "libs/gcp-client/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/gis": [
        "libs/gis/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/document-viewer": [
        "libs/document-viewer/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/secret-manager": [
        "libs/secret-manager/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/gcp/google-secret": [
        "libs/gcp/google-secret/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/viewers": [
        "libs/viewers/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/grid": [
        "libs/grid/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/kind-configuration": [
        "libs/kind-configuration/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@rms-management/utils/kind": [
        "libs/utils/kind/src/index.ts"
      ]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

My **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
      {
          "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
      }
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts",
  ]
}
```

My **tsconfig.spec.json**:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "types": [
          "jest",
          "node"
      ]
  },
  "files": [
      "src/test-setup.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

My **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "rms-management",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "concurrently \"ng serve api --configuration=production\" \"ng serve\"",
    "start:ssl": "concurrently \"ng serve api --configuration=evd\" \"ng serve --ssl --ssl-key C:\\certificates\\localhost.key  --ssl-cert C:\\certificates\\localhost.crt\"  ",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json --extra-webpack-config webpack.compress.js && ng build api --configuration=production",
    "start:evd": "concurrently \"ng serve api --configuration=evd\" \"ng serve\"",
    "start:p4d": "concurrently \"ng serve api --configuration=p4d\" \"ng serve\"",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage --verbose",
    "test:watch": "ng test --code-coverage --watch",
    "test:watch-api": "ng test api --code-coverage --watch",
    "test:watch-rms": "ng test rms-management --code-coverage --watch",
    "test:watch-ui": "ng test ui --code-coverage --watch",
    "lint": "esw . --clear --ext .ts && npm run lint:style",
    "lint:watch": "esw -w . --clear --ext .ts",
    "lint:report": "esw . --ext .ts -f node_modules/eslint-detailed-reporter/lib/detailed.js -o eslint/report.html",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"apps/**/*.scss\" --output-file stylelint-report.log",
    "lint:style-fix": "stylelint \"apps/**/*.scss\" --fix --color  --output-file stylelint-report.log",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/apps/rms-management/stats.json",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build --base=remotes/origin/master --head=HEAD",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:lint": "node --max_old_space_size=12288 ./node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx affected:lint --base=remotes/origin/master --head=HEAD --parallel --maxParallel=12",
    "affected:test": "node --max_old_space_size=12288 ./node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx affected:test --code-coverage --base=remotes/origin/master --head=HEAD --parallel --maxParallel=8",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "update": "ng update @nrwl/workspace",
    "update:check": "ng update",
    "workspace-schematic": "nx workspace-schematic",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help",
    "refreshVSToken": "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-skyhook/core": "1.3.3",
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/google-maps": "11.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.0",
    "@rms-gui/components": "13.1.2193549",
    "@google-cloud/logging": "9.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/logging-bunyan": "3.0.1",
    "@google-cloud/monitoring": "2.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "3.2.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "2.1.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "4.0.0",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "8.0.3",
    "@ngrx/data": "11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "11.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "11.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "11.0.0",
    "@slb-cloud/logstore": "3.0.4",
    "@slb-dls/angular-material": "14.1.0",
    "@slb-dtw-packages/document-viewer-widget": "13.0.4",
    "@slb-dtw-packages/widget-crs-management-ui": "5.0.3",
    "@slb-dtw-packages/widget-dqm-score-summary": "5.2.3",
    "@slb-dtw-packages/wke-document-view": "11.0.4",
    "@slb-innersource/das-dropbox": "18.3.0",
    "@slb-innersource/gis-canvas": "5.0.245",
    "@slb-innersource/trace-viewer": "1.6.0",
    "@slb-innersource/wke-well-view": "23.9.0",
    "@slb-is/ng-geotoolkit": "1.4.0-341",
    "@slb-wellbore/wing-core": "9.0.0-426",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.controls": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.core": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.data": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.deviation": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.gauges": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.legacygauges": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.pdf": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.report": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.schematics": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seislog": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seismic": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seismic.analysis": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seismic.cgmplus": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seismic.compression": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.seismic.widgets": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.svg": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.welllog": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.welllog.multiwell": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.welllog.widgets": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/geotoolkit.widgets": "3.0.95-1",
    "@slbint/three": "3.0.95-1",
    "@splitsoftware/splitio": "10.15.1",
    "@types/filesystem": "0.0.29",
    "@types/uuid": "8.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "23.0.3",
    "ag-grid-community": "23.0.2",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "23.0.2",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "1.10.4",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "11.2.0",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "6.1.1",
    "async": "3.2.0",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "bunyan": "1.8.14",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.3",
    "form-data": "3.0.0",
    "google-auth-library": "6.0.0",
    "googleapis": "49.0.0",
    "helmet": "3.21.2",
    "highcharts": "8.1.2",
    "jest-junit": "10.0.0",
    "jsoneditor": "9.1.7",
    "jszip": "3.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "lucene": "2.1.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "13.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "7.0.1",
    "omni-slider": "1.2.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "10.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "resize-observer": "1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "shpjs": "3.6.3",
    "socket.io-client": "3.0.5",
    "speakeasy": "2.0.0",
    "taggle": "1.14.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "11.2.9",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "7.2.6",
    "@nestjs/testing": "7.6.5",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "11.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "11.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/nest": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/node": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.0.6",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.0.6",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.104",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/puppeteer": "2.1.5",
    "@types/speakeasy": "2.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
    "array.prototype.flatmap": "1.2.4",
    "canvas": "2.7.0",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "concurrently": "5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-detailed-reporter": "0.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.3.2",
    "jest-puppeteer": "4.4.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "11.0.0",
    "pixelmatch": "4.0.2",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "prettier-linter-helpers": "1.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "3.0.2",
    "string.prototype.matchall": "4.0.4",
    "stylelint": "13.3.3",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "7.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.17.1",
    "supertest": "4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.3",
    "ts-node": "8.9.1",
    "tslib": "2.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

I have been playing around with transformIgnorePatterns and allowJs:true and esModuleInterop but to no success.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?